# canvas to pdf error

Tags: c#, pdf, canvas, formatexception

I have application where requirement is like i need to save canvas to pdf document in pop-up.
For that I have used third party tool for converting image data to pdf.

Now how I am doing this:

1. first I created web method which sends canvas data from UI to server
   in JSON format where i convert it to MemoryStream.
2. I call server button click event where I convert MemoryStream to pdf
   document. It is getting created successfully.

But when I returned it using following code:

```
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Buffer = true;
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
        // inform the browser about the binary data format
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/pdf");

        // let the browser know how to open the PDF document
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
          String.Format("{0}; filename=HtmlToPdf.pdf;size={1}", "attachment",           pdfBuffer.Length.ToString()));
     HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(pdfBuffer);
  //HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
HttpContext.Current.ApplicationInstance.CompleteRequest();
```

It gives me following exception:

```
[FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or a non-white space character among the padding characters. ]
   System.Convert.FromBase64String(String s) +0
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.Deserialize(String inputString) +77
   System.Web.UI.ObjectStateFormatter.System.Web.UI.IStateFormatter.Deserialize(String serializedState) +4
   System.Web.UI.Util.DeserializeWithAssert(IStateFormatter formatter, String serializedState) +37
   System.Web.UI.HiddenFieldPageStatePersister.Load() +147

[ViewStateException: Invalid viewstate. 
    Client IP: ::1
    Port: 
    Referer: http://[mysite]/Report.aspx
    Path: /Report.aspx
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; Trident/5.0)
    ViewState: 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...
```

Please help me what am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

This bit of exception seems pretty helpful :

> [FormatException: The input is not a valid Base-64 string as it
>   contains a non-base 64 character, more than two padding characters, or
>   a non-white space character among the padding characters. ]

Try out in this way :

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + FileName );
Response.AddHeader( "Content-Length", strFileSize );
Response.ContentType = "application/pdf" ;
```

Comment: Added this one :Response.AddHeader( "Content-Length", strFileSize );
Other two are already there. but still no luck same error!!!!!!!

Comment: Are you using any third party tool for this? It not then You will have to use 3rd party tool for that Try using iText Sharp library its free. Put your pdfBuffer like HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(pdfBuffer);